# Sequences proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm doing an assignment for my analysis class and need help with the following question:

Let $f$ be a continuous function which is defined on the interval $I = [a, b]$. Assume
that $f$ is not bounded on $I$. Use the fact that $f$ is not bounded to prove that there is a
sequence $(x_n)$ in $I$ for which $|f(x_n)| > n, \forall n \in \mathbb N$

I would really appreciate your help .
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If $ f $ is not bounded on $ I $ then, by definition, given any $ C > 0 $ we can find $ x \in I $ such that $ \vert f(x) \vert > C $. In particular, for each $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ we can pick $ x_n \in I $ with $ \vert f(x_n) \vert > n $.

Comment: Quick question, is that by definition of boundedness?

Comment: Yes. Well, strictly speaking, I'm negating boundedness. Since for a function to be bounded we need the existence of C > 0 such that |f(x)| </= C for all x, for a function to *not* be bounded, we must have that for all C > 0 we can find x with |f(x)| > C.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Much appreciated.